# Prove that $2^{30}$ has at least two repeated digits.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Prove that $2^{30}$ has at least two repeated digits.

I assume that the question is asking me to prove that $2^{30}$ has at least one digit that appears twice. Correct me if I'm wrong. (I later checked $2^{30}$ has three digits each of which appears twice, I initially thought that if I could prove the $2^{30}$ has 11 digits, then I can prove the given, but calculated the number of digits only to find out that it has 10 digits).

Comment: Hint: What is $2^{30} \pmod 9$?

Comment: $2^{30}=1073741824$, so ...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$2^{30}$ has $10$ decimal digits, as $10^9 < 2^{30} < 10^{10}$.  If none were repeated, each of the $10$ digits $0$ to $9$ would appear once.  But if that were the case, the sum of digits would be $45$, which would make the number divisible by $9$, and $2^{30}$ is not.

Comment: This answer seems to depend on convincing yourself that $2^{30}$ has 10 digits without actually multiplying it out or resorting to logarithms (since doing that would violate the spirit of the question).  The programmer in me knows that $2^{10}$ is $1024$.  So $2^{30} = (2^{10})^3$ is a little more than $1000^3$, which is easy to see has 10 digits.